# Is there an R package for Locally Interpretable Model Agnostic Explanations?

Tags: neural-network, r, predictive-modeling, ensemble-modeling

One of the researchers, Marco Ribeiro, who developed this method of explaining how black box models make their decisions has developed a Python implementation of the algorithm available through Github, but has anyone developed a R package? If so, can you report on using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're talking about the `lime` Python package. No, there is **no** R port for the package. The implementation for the localized model requires enhancements to the existing machine-learning code (explained in the paper), a new implementation for R would be very time consuming.

You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11716923/9214357) for interfacing Python in R.

My suggestion is stick with Python. The package is only useful for highly complicated non-linear models, which Python offers better support than R.

Comment: To clarify - when you say 'the paper' do you mean 'Why Should I Trust You?' by Ribeiro, Singh and Guestrin, date stamped 16 Feb 2016 in arXiv?

Comment: @RobertdeGraaf Yes. It is a good paper.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is now a port to R, which is available [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/lime).

It purports to provide LIME explanations for any classifier that implements a `predict()` method accepting a `type = 'prob'` argument. I have not yet tested it myself.

Comment: Great news! (note: comment made before trying it out ;-))